Sleep taking suspend/hibernate into account
The sleep command waits for a certain number of seconds, but if the computer suspends/hibernates, it does not take that into account.
The sleep command can not stop when the computer hibernates, but I'm wondering if there is some tool that thus takes the time into account. This thus means that if you would ask to sleep 2 minutes, and after 1 minute you set the computer to suspend/hibernate, and this takes ~5 minutes for example, sleep immediately terminates after the machine resumes.
So instead of sleeping for a certain amount of (CPU) time, you set a certain point in time that is ~n seconds in the future, and sleep terminates as soon as it is possible after that threshold.
A simple solution is to first determine the tick when the program has to resume, and then use some loop that each time waits for example ~1 minute, checks if the timestamp has been reached, and then continues. But this is thus more active polling.

The clock_nanosleep function takes a TIMER_ABSTIME flag which allows an absolute time at which to wake up. From the documentation not clear what happens across a suspend/hibernate. Are you able to compile a utility from source, or can can you only use tools provided by a Ubuntu installation?
